# How do i do a git pull?

Tags: git, github

Please..can someone explain this?  So...git pull does not work.  Then I specify the branch to pull.

```
git pull development
fatal: 'development' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/workspace/myrepo git pull
You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you
want to merge with, and 'branch.development.merge' in
your configuration file does not tell me, either. Please
specify which branch you want to use on the command line and
try again (e.g. 'git pull <repository> <refspec>').
See git-pull(1) for details.

If you often merge with the same branch, you may want to
use something like the following in your configuration file:
    [branch "development"]
    remote = <nickname>
    merge = <remote-ref>

    [remote "<nickname>"]
    url = <url>
    fetch = <refspec>

See git-config(1) for details.




git branch
* development
  master
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/workspace/myrepo$ git pull development
fatal: 'development' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: Any basic tutorial on Google will get you up to speed. This is such a basic question that you will have 10 more about git right after this.  Voting to close it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to pull from the `development` branch on the remote server, you must explicitly specify it. Like so (assuming the desired remote is `origin`):

```
git pull origin development
```

Otherwise, git will try to pull from the `development` remote (which is not the expected behavior).